# Flow lose literal type in intersection type

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm making my first flow project and I'm stuck with a "strange" behaviour.

Here is a minimalist code that reproduce my problem

```
type PropBase = { name: string }

export type PropTyped =
  | { type: 'string', value: string }
  | { type: 'number', value: number }

export type Prop = PropBase & PropTyped

const p1: Prop = { name: 'prop1', type: 'string', value: 'coucou' };
// Error
const p2: Prop = p1;
```

The error is:

```
10: const p2: Prop = p1;
                     ^ intersection type. This type is incompatible with
7: export type Prop = PropBase & PropTyped
                                 ^ union: object type(s)
```

(Flow v0.47.0, [try flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAIQIYGdoF4oG8oB2qAthAFxTrBwCWBA5lAL4BQLEAHmAnMFKJFiIwAFXAQAJlCwsoUAD55+4igHIqtBqoA0UAG6oANgFdylanUas5i-ALOqCx4gCMIcHfqOmKT1++Y2Tm5eZUF4JGkhJDRMKAAyaNFxCTYAYwQCKigwAEYKCLAo-CJSNTBhXM97NQ1LTwMTBwzjFtVmAG4WDKy+MAAmAuEovI6gA))

Flow seems to "lose" the literal type... But why ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: I've submitted an edit with a smaller example. This is definitely a bug. Feel free to open an issue on https://github.com/facebook/flow

Comment: @NatMote I have open an Issue, but I'm afraid that it it will be lost in the huge number of other issues :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that this is not yet supported by Flow.

A solution is to use the intersection inside each type declaration:

```
export type PropBase = { name: string }

export type PropTyped =
  | { type: 'string', value: string & PropBase }
  | { type: 'number', value: number & PropBase}
```

[Here is a dedicated issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4029), I don't know if there is any short time plan to handle this case.